# How to get large picture size from Facebook graph API for news feed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am stuck with getting picture from Facebook Graph API for news feed with small size. This is the url I get https://fbcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-0/10363492_10202184985725870_7374705736674502849_s.jpg. Not sure how will get the picture with size o.jpg

Comment: What is the API query you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, figured it out. Here is what I did.

NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT pid, object_id, src_big, src_big_width, src_big_height FROM photo WHERE object_id = %@", wallPost[@"object_id"]];  //begins from SELECT........

```
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    query, @"q",
                                    nil];
```

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                                                                id result,
                                                                                                                NSError *error) {
            //do your stuff
            if (!error) {
                NSArray *photo = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

```
             NSString *photoString = [[photo valueForKey:@"src_big"]componentsJoinedByString:@""];
             //NSLog(@"result %@ %@", photoString);

        }
    }];
```